# error in getting the fetching path

Tags: php

I actually trying to check my connection in connection file tester to check if it is connected to the database but the problem is I got this error

```
Warning: include(obj\database_connection\SqlHandler.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/devhostt/public_html/bcc/gradingsystemmodule/root/root.php on line 16

Warning: include(): Failed opening 'obj\database_connection\SqlHandler.php' for inclusion (include_path='/home/devhostt/public_html/bcc/gradingsystemmodule:.:/opt/alt/php55/usr/share/pear:/opt/alt/php55/usr/share/php') in /home/devhostt/public_html/bcc/gradingsystemmodule/root/root.php on line 16

Fatal error: Class 'obj\database_connection\SqlHandler' not found in /home/devhostt/public_html/bcc/gradingsystemmodule/function/checkconnection.php on line 8
```

and here is my code to set & get the path (root.php)

```
<?php
error_reporting( E_ALL );

define("setRealpath", realpath("../"));

const ERROR_EXCEPTION_MESSAGE = "SOMETHING WENT WRONG HERE: ";

try
{
$getPath = array(setRealpath, get_include_path());

if(!set_include_path(implode($getPath, PATH_SEPARATOR)))
{
define("setRealpath", realpath("./"));
$getPath = array(setRealpath, get_include_path());
set_include_path(implode($getPath, PATH_SEPARATOR));
}

function GetClassFile($class)
{
$file = str_replace('/', '\\', $class).".php";
include $file;
}

spl_autoload_register('GetClassFile');

}
catch(Exception $x)
{
die(ERROR_EXCEPTION_MESSAGE.$x->getMessage());
}

?>
```

here is the file where my connection (SqlHandler.php).

```
<?php
namespace obj\connection_database;
use \PDO;
class SqlHandler extends Connection
{
const ERROR_EXCEPTION_MESSAGE = "SOMETHING WENT WRONG HERE:";

protected $db = null;

public function __construct()
{
$this->db = $this->getConnection();
}

public function checkConnection()
{
if($this->db)
{
return "CONNECTED";
}
return "NO CONNECTION";
}
}
?>
```

and lastly here in this file where i'm trying to check the connection(checkconnection.php)

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);

include "./root/root.php";

use \obj\database_connection\SqlHandler;

$checkConnection = new SqlHandler;

echo $checkConnection->checkConnection();
?>
```

Comment: `Failed opening 'obj\database_connection\SqlHandler.php'` this doesn't give you a clue?

Comment: And no need to scream.

Comment: @yivi i actually found my mistakes, the only problem is that i'm using the old version of php. haha my bad. but thanks

Comment: Glad you did. Good for you. :) Delete your question then, it's no use to anyone like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

now i found my mistake, the only mistake is that i'm using the old version of php, instead of using php 7.1 version , i'm using php 5. so i change it and it works.